# Failed to decode downloaded font - Chrome and base64

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, fonts, base64

I am converting fonts from opentype.js to base64 using this method:

```
const buffer = glyphs.toArrayBuffer() // from opentype
let binary = []
const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer)
const len = bytes.byteLength
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  binary[i] = String.fromCharCode(bytes[ i ])
}
return window.btoa(binary.join(''))
```

I take this base64 string and embed it as a css string:

```
src: url('data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,BASE64DARA')
```

95% of fonts work in Chrome and 100% in Safari. Some fonts fail in Chrome with

```
Failed to decode downloaded font
```

If I encode the font using a more native approach such as the CLI it works fine. I have read that the browser method above leaves to be desired fo multi bytes but it works fine in Safari and also decodes back to the ttf.

I have played around with a few variations of the encoder=, mime types etc to no avail.

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/4361c85d339e1cbcbef1d644b6345404) of the offending base64.

How do I make this wok in Chrome?